# Incrementing +1 the class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im doing a PHP loop where I set a class, this loop make a list of items, and each one of them will have a "share" button that will open a window, (div display:none) the javascript open this div, and it works perfect..

My problem is that in this moment I have inserted the `<script>` code inside the loop so each item has its own `<script></script>` code...

Is there any way to do just one  and take that code out of the php loop, so I can improve the code.

```
  <script>
  $('a.sharebtnc').click(
            function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('div.redescompartir').fadeToggle(300);

            }
        );
  </script>
```

In the Loop well I just add to the class the id like this (id :32 )

```
  <script>
  $('a.sharebtnc32').click(
            function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('div.redescompartir32').fadeToggle(300);

            }
        );
  </script>
```

How can I make this script works for all elements no matter the id number, I have no idea, but I know this is the correct way of doing this , right?

The HTML is very simple, its the same for each item... I mean each item has its own div with for `<a href="" > </a>` elements

```
<a href="#" class="sharebtnc(id)"> 
<div class="redescompartir(id)">
<a href="" >Twitter </a>
<a href="" >Facebook </a>
<a href="" >Google </a>
<a href="" >Foursquare </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the DOM look like? Is the `input` a child, parent, or sibling of the `div`? The right way to do this is to use `this` to refer to the clicked element, then traverse to the target you want to toggle.

Comment: the div is a normal div i will paste my code, but its a normal div with four a href elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new class and attribute to the input element like

instead of

```
<a class="sharebtnc32" />
```

use

```
<a class="sharebtnc sharebtnc32" data-id="32"/>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.sharebtnctl').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.redesopenclose' + $(this).data('id')).fadeToggle(300);
    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt make the right question , the class attribute its done in php loop so i get like 80 classes for example, with the class sharebtnid... (example sharebtn32 sharebtn33 etc) i need a universal code for all of them to save lines in the javascript

Comment: @MonchoChavez still you can have multiple classes for a element

Comment: i didnt see the last part, will acept in a min

Comment: What am i doing wrog i cut & copy one example of the site http://jsfiddle.net/LSNXQ/

Comment: @MonchoChavez see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xX7A6/1/  the class name `redescompartir113` should be `redesopenclose113`

Comment: I copied the code into jsfiddle its working, but not in my site, i think it was jquery version, but no.. its something in my web http://jsfiddle.net/6LVen/

Comment: damn it was a css problem =S sorry

Comment: I cant make it work =( so sad, its just not working on my site , but if i copy the paste out its working ok, http://jsfiddle.net/jenz9/  here is the url to my site, http://tinyurl.com/jwhgpay

Comment: @MonchoChavez your script should be within a dom ready handler... see the update

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method: PHP to generate link between the two elements, then a small snippet of JS to grab which particular one was clicked.

PHP:

```
$num = 100;

for ($x = 0; $x < $numItems; $x++) {
    echo "
    <a href='#' class='sharebtn' target='$x'>Share</a>

    <div class='redescompartir' id='$x'>
    <a href=''>Twitter</a>
    <a href=''>Facebook</a>
    <a href=''>Google</a>
    <a href=''>Foursquare</a>
    </div>
    ";

}
```

HTML output:

```
<a href="#" class="sharebtn" target='32'>Share</a>

<div class="redescompartir" id='32'>
<a href="" >Twitter </a>
<a href="" >Facebook </a>
<a href="" >Google </a>
<a href="" >Foursquare </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('a.sharebtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr('target');
    $('#'+target).fadeToggle(300);
});
```

This way you only need a single `<script></script>` tag, which your user's broswers will thank you for. :)

Comment: Thanks i will test i already have the PHP working fine :D, i know php my problem its with java thanks let me try